# How do I return data that is ordered today in C# or SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have table in my SQL Server database called `OrderDetail` which stores the order data. I have a column in this table called `OrderDate` which stores the date and time information about the orders.

I want to retrieve all those orders from `OrderDetail` table which were created today.

My scenario is that I want to make a button which will click by admin at night to see that how many orders are done today?

Any help regard to this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SELECT A.OrderID, ...
FROM OrderDetail as 'A' INNER JOIN OrderDate as 'B' ON 
        A.OrderID = B.OrderID
WHERE B.DateOfOrder BETWEEN '5/20/2011 00:00:00' AND '5/20/2011 23:59:59'
```

I assumed that you have `ID` in your `OrderDetail` and that `ID` is the same in the `OrderDate` table.

Comment: How could i do this in c#. i mean extract date from datetime

Comment: @DigitalAssets that would depend on how you're connecting to the database from C# - ADO.NET, Linq-To-SQL, EF...? Something else...?

Comment: @DigitalAssets you need to be more clear on what you are asking for. Your question lacks information. Providing the schema of your table will help. Are you developing in winforms?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from OrderDetails
where cast(OrderDate as date) = '2012-03-11'
```

If you want to extract the date part from a `DateTime` in C# then do this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d = dt.Date;
//or if you want a string
string dStr = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: i have used datetime datatype. How do i extract date from it.

Comment: OP didn't mention if it's SQL Server 2008. He/she may/may not have acceess to `DATE` data type.

Comment: @YS.: `DATE` is not a new data type in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @juergend - yes it is new in 2008, prior to that - there's only `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM OrderDetail 
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, OrderDate)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

`DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, OrderDate)` << this is to get rid of the time portion.

Comment: How could i do this in c#. i mean extract date from datetime.

Comment: why does it need to be done in c# if it can be done in sql server already ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderDetails
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderDate , 101)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101);
```